# fetch stored procedure params names and values

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use the same catch code in all my stored procedures. Everything works fine, but don't know how to get list of all parameter names and values.

```
CREATE procedure addNewItem @messageNo integer out,
                            @message nvarchar(4000) out,
                            @companyId smallint,
                            @itemNumber bigint,
                            @itemDescription nvarchar(4000)
as
begin try
    Set @companyId = 'a'  
end try
begin catch
    if ERROR_SEVERITY() = 11
    begin
        Set @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        Set @messageNo = ERROR_STATE() * (-1)
    end
    else
    begin
        Set @message = 'Error. Please, contact support.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        Set @message = @message + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'PARAMS: ???' + /* get params somehow */ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'ERROR_NUMBER: ' + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as nvarchar) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'ERROR PROCEDURE: ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE () + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
                'ERROR LINE: ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar)
        Set @messageNo = ERROR_NUMBER() * (-1)
    end

end catch
```

exec

```
-- execution
declare @messageNo integer,
        @message nvarchar(4000)
exec addNewItem @messageNo out, @message out, 1, 1, 'New Item'             
print @message
```

I would like to get all parameters name with values in line with 'PARAMS: ' but I have no idea how to do that. Each one procedure has the same @MesageNo and @message, but all others parameters count, name and values can be different in each procedure.

I would like to get sht like:

```
Error. Please, contact support.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type smallint.
PARAMS: 'companyId: 1; itemNumber: 1; itemDescription: New Item'
ERROR_NUMBER: 245
ERROR PROCEDURE: addNewItem
ERROR LINE: 8
```

Thanks for any help.

I have created sth like this:

```
declare @results varchar(4000)
SELECT @results = coalesce(@results + ' + ', '') + convert(varchar(200), '''; ' + P.name + ': '' + cast(') + convert(varchar(200), P.name) + ' as nvarchar)'
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P 
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE NAME = 'addNewItem') and P.name not in ('@messageNo', '@message')
Set @results = '''' + SUBSTRING(@results, 4, LEN(@results))
print @results
```

where result is STRING:

```
'@companyId: ' + cast(@companyId as nvarchar) + '; @itemNumber: ' + cast(@itemNumber as nvarchar) + '; @itemDescription: ' + cast(@itemDescription as nvarchar)
```

but I have no idea how to execute it, When I use EXECUTE sp_executesql I get a message that I have to declare variables :(

Comment: It is possible to write SQL to log all the parameters the sproc has, but it's not possible to actually log their values, because any `EXEC` statement will not have the variables in scope. And you can't pass them either, since that would required you know their names first. In short: you can't do this with one fully generic block of code. You are almost certainly better off handling these errors in client code, which has full access to parameters as well as the intended purpose of the call.

Comment: It seems like you're requesting that when any stored procedure (with parameters) is executed and then an error occurs, you want to call a standard (external) procedure to handle the logging of calling procedure's error and parameters?